Calculating Difference Between 2 Matrices
I am trying to calculate percentage differences of 25 different 'steps' across 2 $5\times5$ matrices, named $A$ and $B$.
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}23507&30500&25677&53144&41734\\
23743&30652&25934&53675&44238\\
23980&30805&26193&54212&46892\\
24220&30959&26455&54754&49706\\
24462&31114&26719&55302&52688
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the next matrix:
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}23743&30652&25934&53675&44238\\
23980&30805&26193&54212&46892\\
24220&30959&26455&54754&49706\\
24462&31114&26719&55302&52688\\
24707&31270&26987&55855&55849
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The matrices can be found in this image.
I need to calculate the percentage difference between the red outline (matrix A) and the blue outline (matrix B). I do not know if it helps that they overlap. I have tried B/A but it just returns as in the following image:

If your array is $M(i,j), 1\leq i \leq 6, 1\leq j \leq 5$, your red matrix is for indices  $1\leq i \leq 5$ and the blue matrix for  $2\leq i \leq 6$. Right ? Could you explain something which isn't clear at all : what are you calling the "percentage differences of the 25 steps" in mathematical notations such as $M(i,j)-M(i',j)$ for $i=...$ for $i'=...$, for $j=...$ ? What do you mean in particular by "percentage" here ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@JeanMarie I'm trying to find the percentage difference between M(1,1) and M(2,1), Then the percentage difference between M(2,1) and M(3,1). So on for the rest of that column (should end up having 5 values), then repeating that process for the other 5 columns - 25 total. I, of course, know the way to do this normally and have done so in excel, but I am asking if it is possible using matrices and if so, how? And what I mean by percentage is, for example, the percentage increase between M(1,1) and M(2,1) is 1.004% - 23507 to 23743.

I am still puzzled by the word percentage, do you mean for example $|M(1,1)-M(2,1)|/M(1,1)$ ?

@JeanMarie Yes, but that formula for all values in the array.

Is your question about 1) an "algorithmic" way to solve this issue  (by the way do you use a specific language such as Matlab ?) 2) or a "denotational" way, i.e., the objective being to write this operation in terms of a succession of "clean" matrix operations ?

@JeanMarie The latter, thank you. Also sorry for all of the back and forth follow up questions, I am new to this site and have no idea how to use it...

If you use Matlab, take $abs(B-A)./abs(B)$ (the point-slash operator meaning "division entrywise").

@JeanMarie I do not use Matlab. I have just checked and my school doesn't have a subscription of any sorts. Do you have any alternatives? And also what is division entrywise?

@w1ndnd Check if my edit on the matrices are ok. Moreover, if you do not use MathLab or are not satisfied with excel, the only choice is to write a program by yourself, I guess.

I have tried $B/A$. What does that mean?

@M.Riyan B/A, basically just X=B*A^-1

Here is a Python program which does the job :
import numpy as np
m1 = np.array([[-4, 8, 12],
[16, 20, 24]])
m2 = np.array([[2, 4, 6],
[8, 10, 12]])
m3 = abs((m1-m2) / m2)
print(m3)
L=list(np.array(m3).flat)
print(L)
print(max(L))

As per your comments, if I go ahead, the differences between the matrices [I could not take any advantage of the fact that some of their rows overlap]:
$$
|A-B|=\begin{bmatrix}236&152&257&531&2504\\
237&
153&
259&
537&
2654\\
240&
154&
262&
542&
2814\\
242&
155&
264&
548&
2982\\
245&
156&
268&
553&
3161
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now, if you want to find the entry-wise percentage change, you can divide each entries with the corresponding entries of $A$.
$$
\text{change}=\begin{bmatrix}1.004&
0.498&
1.001&
0.999&
6.000\\
0.998&
0.499&
0.999&
1.000&
5.999\\
1.001&
0.500&
1.000&
1.000&
6.001\\
0.999&
0.501&
0.998&
1.001&
5.999\\
1.002&
0.501&
1.003&
1.000&
5.999\end{bmatrix}
$$
Is this what you are looking for?
